# Changing color of text depending on if condition is met

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to make it so that if the `$status` is set to admin, then when the user status is echoed out: `<h3>Status: <?php echo $status; ?></h3>` the color of the text $status should be set to red. I'm not really sure on how to go about it.

```
 <?php
    $admin = 1;
    if($admin == 1){
        $status = "Admin";
    }
    else{
        $status = "User";
    }
    <h3>Status: <?php echo $status; ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different ways you can do this, but the quickest way is to just set the colour in the variable when you set it to the value you want.

```
<?php

$admin = 1;

if ( $admin == 1 ){
    $status = '<span style="color: red;">Admin</span>';
} else {
    $status = 'User';
}

?>

<h3>Status: <?php echo $status; ?></h3>
```

Do note though that because you're setting `$admin` to `1` at the start, it'll always default to admin and and not user. You'll need some extra logic there to change that based on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$admin = 1;
if($admin == 1){
    $status = "Admin";
}
else{
    $status = "User";
}
?>
<h3 <?php if($status === "Admin"){ echo "class='red'";}?>>Status: <?php echo $status; ?></h3>
```

and add your CSS style for `.red`

Hope this helps